# Bazel: Use swig from non-standard location

Tags: build, swig, tensorflow, bazel

Because I don't have root access on my machine, I have built and installed swig from source in a non-standard directory (`/scratch/swig/build`) and I want bazel to use it. So when I try to build tensorflow, I get the error that swig cannot be found:

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From SWIGing tensorflow/python/tensorflow.i:
bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/swig: line 17: swig: command not found
```

Checking the `swig` script mentioned in the error it's just a script that does:

```
#!/bin/bash
swig "$@"
```

Printing the `$PATH` from this script shows it's:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:.
```

I can't append the $PATH variable in the swig script because it gets remade on build. So how do I tell bazel to use my non-standard swig location?

Answer (score 2):

That isn't Bazel-specific, it's part of the tensorflow code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/swig/swig.sh

You can just modify that file before you build.

The specific build rule that uses that file is also defined by tensorflow, since it's not a rule included with the core Bazel distribution:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L275

Comment: I modified `swig.sh`, and now I get `bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/swig: line 3: /scratch/package/install/bin/swig: No such file or directory`. I got the swig dir by running `which swig`. If I replace swig.sh with the swig binary, I get an error that it can't find `swig.swg` and `python.swg`

Comment: How did you modify `swig.sh`?

Comment: I changed it to: `/scratch/package/install/bin/swig "$@"`. After, I added some `ls` statements to the script and it seems that bazel can't actually see this directory (it can only see a very few limited number of directories and files within them).

Answer (score 2):

This problem looks like it is due to [Bazel Sandboxing](http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing).

If so, then using the following Bazel options should workaround the problem, as it turns sandboxing off:

```
--spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone
```

I have not tested this, though.

This [blog post](http://bazel.io/blog/2015/09/11/sandboxing.html) explains:

> Sandboxing is the technique of restricting the access rights of a
>   process. In the context of Bazel, we're mostly concerned with
>   restricting file system access. More specifically, Bazel's file system
>   sandbox contains only known inputs, such that compilers and other
>   tools can't even see files they should not access.

How it works on Linux:

> On Linux, we're using user namespaces, which are available in Linux
>   3.8 and later. Specifically, we create a new mount namespace. We create a temporary directory into which we mount all the files that
>   the subprocess is allowed to see. We then use pivot_root to make the
>   temporary directory appear as the root directory for all subprocesses.
>
> We also mount /proc, /dev/null, /dev/zero, and a temporary filesystem
>   (tmpfs) on /tmp. We mount /dev/random and /dev/urandom, but recommend
>   against their usage, as it can lead to non-reproducible builds.
>
> We currently also mount /bin, /etc, /usr (except /usr/local), and
>   every directory starting with /lib, to allow running local tools. In
>   the future, we are planning to provide a shell with a set of Linux
>   utilities, and to require that all other tools are specified as
>   inputs.

[Bazel's roadmap](http://bazel.io/roadmap.html) says that sandboxing on MacOSX is scheduled for April 2016.

Sandboxing is supposed to be a good thing, since it guarantees that build rules are consistent (as any dependency that is not made explicit will bomb).  So perhaps instead of turning Sandboxing off, better solutions would be:

- fixing TensorFlow's build rules to make the dependency to swig explicit.
- or making swig available in one of the directories above (eg. `/bin`).
- or explicitly configuring Bazel to mount the directory that swig lives in (if may be possible with `-M` and `-m`, I have not tested though).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I fixed it by getting the sysadmin to install swig on my machine.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW Oh ok, sounds good.  I would have been curious to know if my answer works.  We'll just have to wait for someone else to have the same problem.  Cheers!